# Spring Transactional Parameterized Test and Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, junit

Is there a way to get a class that extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContexts to play nicely with JUnit's own @RunWith(Parameterized.class), so that fields marked as Autowired get wired in properly?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Foo extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired private Bar bar

    @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        // return parameters, following pattern in
        // http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html
    }

    @Test public void someTest(){
        bar.baz() //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContexts` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Should be fixed now, as well as the ".class" on Parameterized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5292
There is a solution.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, that'll be a huge help.

Comment: I have used this solution. Be careful, they define their own Parameters annotation. When the code invokes getParametersMethod(final TestClass testClass) then testClass.getAnnotatedMethods(Parameters.class); will return and empty list. When you remove     
public static @interface Parameters {} it's starting to work as expected...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a TestContextManager from Spring. In this example, I'm using Theories instead of Parameterized.

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring-context.xml")
public class SeleniumCase {
  @DataPoints
  public static WebDriver[] drivers() {
    return new WebDriver[] { firefoxDriver, internetExplorerDriver };
  }

  private TestContextManager testContextManager;

  @Autowired
  SomethingDao dao;

  private static FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
  private static InternetExplorerDriver internetExplorerDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDown() {
    firefoxDriver.close();
    internetExplorerDriver.close();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUpStringContext() throws Exception {
    testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
    testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
  }

  @Theory
  public void testWork(WebDriver driver) {
    assertNotNull(driver);
    assertNotNull(dao);
  }
}
```

I found this solution here : [How to do Parameterized/Theories tests with Spring](http://bmocanu.ro/coding/320/combining-junit-theoriesparameterized-tests-with-spring/)

Comment: this option wouldn't support things like @BeforeTransaction, would it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SpringClassRule](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html) and [SpringMethodRule](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringMethodRule.html) for this purpose

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(...)
public class FooTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired 
    private Bar bar

    @Parameters 
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        // return parameters, following pattern in
        // http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html
    }

    @Test 
    public void someTest() {
        bar.baz() //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The superclass has:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

which assures that the tests are run within spring context. If you replace it, you are losing this.

What comes to my mind as an alternative is to extend `SpringJunit4ClassRunner`, provide your custom functionality there and use it with `@RunWith(..)`. Thus you will have the spring context + your additional functionality. It will call `super.createTest(..)` and then perform additional stuff on the test.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion (must be a good idea then).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to handle the transactions programmatically (see http://www.javathinking.com/2011/09/junit-parameterized-test-with-spring-autowiring-and-transactions/):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/testContext.xml")
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private TestContextManager testContextManager;

    public MyTest (... parameters for test) {
        // store parameters in instance variables
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpSpringContext() throws Exception {
        testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> generateData() throws Exception {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        // add data for each test here
        return list;
    }

    @Test
    public void validDataShouldLoadFully() throws Exception {
        new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallback() {
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                status.setRollbackOnly();
                try {
                    ... do cool stuff here

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made it work in Spring Boot `1.5.7`:

1. Add the `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` annotation to your class
2. Inject your dependency as class field with:

   ```java
   @Autowired
   private Bar bar;
   ```
3. Add your parameter/s as class fields:

   ```java
   private final int qux;
   private final Boolean corge;
   private final String grault;
   ```
4. Add a constructor to initialize the parameter/s as follows:

   ```java
    public Foo(int qux, Boolean corge, String grault) throws Exception {
        this.qux = qux;
        this.corge = corge;
        this.grault = grault;
        new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this);
    }
   ```
5. Add a static method `data` that returns a Collection containing the values of your parameters at each iteration, respecting the order by which they are passed to the constructor:

   ```java
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                { 1, Boolean.FALSE, "Hello" },
                { 2, Boolean.TRUE, null },
                { 3, null, "world" }
        });
    }
   ```
6. Write your test using the class fields declared above like follows:

   ```java
   @Test public void someTest(){
       // Some arrangements

       // Some actions

       assertThat(myTestedIntValue, is(equalTo(qux));
       assertThat(myTestedBooleanValue, is(equalTo(corge));
       assertThat(myTestedStringValue, is(equalTo(grault));
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by Simon's solution, you can use TestContextManager also with Parameterized runner:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring-context.xml")
public class MyTestClass {

  @Parameters public static Collection data() {
    // return parameters, following pattern in
    // http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this);
  }

}
```

Here is [full example](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/)

I am not sure about handling @Transactional in this case.

Comment: I have tested that @Transactional annotations are not handled by TestContextManager

Comment: `@Michal` the link is broken